# early_stopping set to False, but iteration stops before max_iter in Sklearn MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I work on sklearn MLPClassifier for making neural network model

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
clf = MLPClassifier(activation='logistic', learning_rate_init=0.5, early_stopping=False, max_iter=500, random_state=42, hidden_layer_sizes=(10,1)).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I set early_stopping to False, and set max_iter to 500. It stops on 41st iteration and gets loss=0.0989939. Why it didn't reach maximum iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the descriptions of the parameters `tol` and `n_iter_no_change`: if the weights converge sufficiently, then learning will stop early.

That's distinct from the use of `early_stopping`, which cuts short the learning when a *validation* score stops improving (generally, worsens because of overfitting).  In your case, the model's weights just aren't moving enough to justify further calculations.  If you really want to reach 500 iterations, you can set `tol=0` or `n_iter_no_change=500`.